# Overhead valve Vs Overhead cam

Tags: engine, engine-theory

Sure overhead cam is better at high revs because valve accuracy is superior.At normal average revs like say 3000rpm the advantage is not really there but the extra cams will chew more mechanical power due to extra friction possibly affecting fuel economy .for a V8 you are talking 4 cams Vs 1 cam .How much power does a camshaft waste? is there a simple rule depending on cylinder size ,number of cylinders ,lift ,number of valves?

Comment: Are you just talking about the extra friction on the cam bearings?  You have to also take into account the extra moving parts on a push rod engine.  No need for a rocker shaft on some OHC engines.

Comment: I'm voting to close.  This is not really a Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair question.  More appropriate in Engineering.

Comment: @jwh20 I don't see an issue asking questions about engine design.  It is far more appropriate to this site than some questions, for example "Cleaning up spilled loctite thread locking compound", yet they get answered.  I would, however,  be very surprised if anyone can answer the question "How much power does a camshaft waste?".  I think the question should be reworded to get an answer.

Comment: My point is that this is more of an engineering/design question not a maintenance question.    This is probably a better topic area: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @jwh20 - This falls under the [tag:engine-theory] portion of things. We've answered plenty of questions along this line. Agree with HandyHowie on cleaning up the question some, though.